# Stripe PHP Create customer and add subscription

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

The old way of doing this was as follows

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "description" => $domain,
    "email" => $email,
    "source" => $token,
    "metadata" => array(
        "name" => $name,
        "phone" => $phone
    ),
));

$cus = $customer->id;

\Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => $cus,
    "plan" => "1",
));
```

But now I do not see the "PLAN" option on the subscription create. Here is what I have so far...

```
$customer = $stripe->customers->create([
  'description' => 'Description text here nomadweb.design',
  'name' => 'Sammy Malones',
  'email' => 'name@email.com',
  'phone' => '5124592222'
]);

$cus = $customer->id;

$stripe->subscriptions->create([
    'customer' => $cus,
    'plan' => '1'
]);
```

In the API Docs is says that it's required to use the items parameter.
My question is how to I add a subscription to a customer with the newer api?

This is their code but I don't understand

```
$stripe->subscriptions->create([
  'customer' => 'cus_J34i3JonNQQXdO',
  'items' => [
    ['price' => 'price_0IQyZLH7HxDXZRHqJfpwwqBB'],
  ],
]);
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create

In my stripe dashboard I have a product created which is a monthly subscription, it has an ID like **prod_BlMuxdEQJSxfKJ** So I'm guessing I need to pass that ID in somehow as an item?

Comment: Plans got replaced with prices. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/migrating-prices

Answer (score 4):

I would encourage you to [read about Prices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide), the successor to Plans, but you can also provide an existing Plan like `plan_123` to the subscription creation request, and it will be converted to a Price for you:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->create([
  'customer' => 'cus_123',
  'items' => [
    ['price' => 'plan_123'],
  ],
]);
```

You can't provide a Product here directly, as Products are not directly tied to any amount or interval. You need to [create Prices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide#create-prices) for those Products, either using the API or your Dashboard.

When creating a subscription, you can optionally [define the recurring pricing ad-hoc](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide#ad-hoc), using `price_data` ([API doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-items-price_data)) and referencing the Product to be used:

```
$subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
  'customer' => 'cus_123',
  'items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'unit_amount' => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'product' => 'prod_456',
      'recurring' => [
        'interval' => 'month',
      ],
    ],
  ]],
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to Nolan, it looks like you need to grab the product pricing API ID which is provided in the dashboard.

Here is the updated code

```
$stripe->subscriptions->create([
    'customer' => $cid,
    'items' => [['price' => 'price_0IR0OGH7HxDXZRHq3sIg9biB'],],
]);
```

Here the price ID is attaching the product which is a subscription to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel and stripe php sdk with it then you can do it like this below:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY'));

        // Use an existing Customer ID if this is a returning customer.
        // $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        //     "description" => $domain,
        //     "email" => $email,
        //     "source" => $token,
        //     "metadata" => [
        //         "name" => $name,
        //         "phone" => $phone
        //     ],
        // ]);

        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create();

        // $customer_id = $customer->id;

        $Subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
            
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'items' => [[
                'price' => $price_id,
            ]],
            'payment_behavior' => 'default_incomplete',
            'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
        ]);

        $ephemeralKey = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(
            ['customer' => $customer->id],
            ['stripe_version' => '2020-08-27']
        );

        // $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        //     'amount' => $amount,
        //     'currency' => $currency,
        //     'customer' => $customer->id
        // ]);
          
        $response = [
            'request' => $data,
            'paymentIntent' => $subscription->latest_invoice->payment_intent->client_secret,
            'ephemeralKey' => $ephemeralKey->secret,
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'subscriptionId' => $subscription->id,
        ];
          
        return response($response, 200);
```

And then in your front end you can process the payment with the help of your paymentIntent secret.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $stripe = new StripeClient(
           stripe_secret
       );

   $stripeToken = $stripe->tokens->create([
                    'card' => [
                        'number' => $request->card_number,
                        'exp_month' =>$request->exp_month,
                        'exp_year' =>$request->exp_year,
                        'cvc' => $request->cvc,
                    ],
    
     $product = $stripe->products->create([
                'name' => "Product Name",
            ]);
     $stripe_plan = $stripe->plans->create([
                'amount' => 60 * 100,
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'interval' => 1,
                'product' => $product->id,
            ]);
    
  
            $stripe_customer = $stripe->customers->create([
                            'name' => $request->name,
                            'email' => $request->email,
                            'source' => $stripeToken['id']
                        ]);
                        $customer_id = $stripe_customer->id;
    
     $subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
                    'customer' => $customer_id,
                    'items' => [[
                        'price' => $stripe_plan->id,
                    ]],
                ]);
```